# Check array of json object is subset of another array of json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I want to check if each array in `testEdge` belongs to `newarr` and return the id that matches for each array in `testEdge`

```
const testEdge = [
  [{
    id: '0',
    from: '0',
    to: '1'
  }, {
    id: '1',
    from: '1',
    to: '3'
  }],
  [{
    id: '2',
    from: '0',
    to: '2'
  }, {
    id: '5',
    from: '2',
    to: '3'
  }],
  [{
    id: '0',
    from: '0',
    to: '1'
  }, {
    id: '6',
    from: '1',
    to: '4'
  }, {
    id: '7',
    from: '4',
    to: '6'
  }]
];

const newarr = [{
  id: 0,
  from: "0",
  to: "1"
}, {
  id: 1,
  from: "1",
  to: "3"
}, {
  id: 2,
  from: "0",
  to: "2"
}, {
  id: 3,
  from: "1",
  to: "4"
}]



// Cannot check
```

I need JavaScript code

The above is the data, Please help me check.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @brk I believe it's a Boolean.

Comment: I expect true or false

Comment: @JackBashford yes just boolean is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testEdge` is an array of arrays & `newarr` is an array of objects. But `id` in newarr is a number. So you need to convert this to string before comparison.

Also you can convert the `testEdge` array of arrays to a single array using `flat` and use `map` on `newarr` to return a new array `stringifyNewArr` which conytain stringified objects. Then use `includes` to check if each value in testEdge is present in `stringifyNewArr`

Following this again use `map` on `testEdge` and use `JSON.stringify` to convert each object to string and use `includes` to check i

```js
const testEdge = [
  [{
    id: '0',
    from: '0',
    to: '1'
  }, {
    id: '1',
    from: '1',
    to: '3'
  }],
  [{
    id: '2',
    from: '0',
    to: '2'
  }, {
    id: '5',
    from: '2',
    to: '3'
  }],
  [{
    id: '0',
    from: '0',
    to: '1'
  }, {
    id: '6',
    from: '1',
    to: '4'
  }, {
    id: '7',
    from: '4',
    to: '6'
  }]
];
const newarr = [{
  id: 0,
  from: "0",
  to: "1"
}, {
  id: 1,
  from: "1",
  to: "3"
}, {
  id: 2,
  from: "0",
  to: "2"
}, {
  id: 3,
  from: "1",
  to: "4"
}]
let stringifyNewArr = newarr.map(function(item) {
  let newItem = {
    id: item.id.toString(),
    from: item.from,
    to: item.to
  }
  return JSON.stringify(newItem)

});

let isSameWithNewArr = testEdge.flat().map(function(item) {
  let isSame;


  if (stringifyNewArr.includes(JSON.stringify(item))) {
    isSame = true;
  } else {
    isSame = false
  }
  return isSame;
});

console.log(isSameWithNewArr)
```

Comment: Thanks @brk for the solution

Comment: @MonishDe happy to help

Answer (score 0):

First you can convert `newarr` to `strings` using `JSON.stringify`. And then use [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if all the elements of `textEdge` are present in `newarr`

```js
const testEdge = [
  [{ id: '0', from: '0', to: '1' }, { id: '1',from: '1', to: '3' }],
  [{ id: '2',from: '0', to: '2' }, { id: '5',from: '2', to: '3' }],
  [{ id: '0',from: '0', to: '1' }, { id: '6',from: '1', to: '4' }, { id: '7',from: '4', to: '6' }]
];
const newarr = [{id: '0', from: "0", to: "1"}, {id: '1', from: "1", to: "3"}, {id: '2', from: "0", to: "2"}, {id: '3', from: "1", to: "4"}]


let objStrings = newarr.map(x => JSON.stringify(x));


function check(arr1,arr2){
   return arr1.every(x => objStrings.includes(JSON.stringify(x)));
}


console.log(check(testEdge[0],objStrings)); //true
console.log(check(testEdge[1],objStrings)); //false
console.log(check(testEdge[2],objStrings)); //fals
```

Comment: It should show true for the first array in testEdge and false for the other two array in testEdge.

Comment: No, you got it wrong Maheer, I want to check for each array in testEdge, if the objects are present in newarr. For example, in the first array id: 0 and id: 1 are present in newarr so true and for second array id:2 is present but id:5 is not present so false.

Comment: Hey, @Maheer Ali can you get me the id that are matching for each arr in testEdge?

Comment: `id` in `newarr` is a number and not string